# python - Error unsupported operand on my code

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop, division

Can someone fix my code? I have a syntax error I don't understand.

```
import random
n= int (0)
sum1=int (0)
temp=int (0)
num=int
gennum = int
count= (0)
outputs= (0)
calculated = int (sum1/gennum)
while count > 3:
    max = int (input("enter a max value:"))
    min = int (input("enter a minimum value:"))
    gennum = int (input("how many numbers do you want to generate?"))
    if min>max:
        temp=min
        min=max
        max=temp
    while n < gennum:
        num=(random.randint(min,max))
        sum1 = sum1 + num
        print (num)
        n=n+1
        count = count + 1
    print("this is the averages",calculated)
print("this is the maximum",max)

print("this is the maximum",max)
```

What's wrong with above code? I don't know what's wrong.

### Error

> The IDE says that its a unsupported operand type at line 9,
>   at

```
calculated = int (sum1/gennum)
```

Comment: The `while` block isn't indented.

Comment: what is n and count and sum1?

Comment: what is the error message you receive ?

Comment: it says theres a syntax error to find calculated

Comment: It cant find `calculated` as you havent declared or defined it in the code you provided, just like n and count and sum1.

Comment: A syntax error will not generate a stack trace.  It's at parse time.

Comment: @adenli:  What's the solution?  Others may find it useful.

Comment: Copying and pasting the code as you're showing it into Python 3.4 gives an `IndentationError` (not a more general `SyntaxError`) so I guess you're showing code different from what you're running.  Now you say "to find calculated", but there **is** no code that you show that does anything to find, compute, or make `calculated` -- just one attempt to print this undefined variable, which is an error but not a **syntax** error.  To add one more clue to the mystery, you tag `division` and there is **no** division at all in the code you're showing us!!!  Don't you **want** help?!

Comment: Your variable are incorrectly initialized: `num=int` `gennum = int`. This does not make num and gennum  an integers. This only assigns an object representing int function to num and gennum.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code so that it at least executes/compiles on python 3.4. Basically `num=int` and  `gennum = int` are problems. This does not make `num` and `gennum` an integers. This only assigns an object representing `int()` function to `num` and `gennum`.

```
import random

n= 0
sum1=0
temp=0
num=0
gennum = 0
count= 0
outputs= 0
calculated = 0

while count < 3:
    max = int (input("enter a max value:"))
    min = int (input("enter a minimum value:"))
    gennum = int (input("how many numbers do you want to generate?"))
    if min>max:
        temp=min
        min=max
        max=temp
    while n < gennum:
        num=(random.randint(min,max))
        sum1 = sum1 + num
        print (num)
        n=n+1
        count = count + 1
    print("this is the averages",calculated)

print("this is the maximum",max)
```

But whether it does what you want it to do is a different question. I cant answer to it, as I don't know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
num=int
gennum = int
```

These aren't initialized correctly, so when you do `calculated = int (sum1/gennum)`, it will attempt to divide an instance of an int (`sum1`, which is 0) by the built-in type `int`, which will cause an error along the lines of `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'type'`.

Comment: @adenli, just replace them with `int(0)` like you do for the rest of your initializations.

Comment: @adenli, and edit the subject -- it still says you have a syntax error, which you definitely **don't**.  You have many errors (e.g you'll always print that the "averages" are 0 since you never recompute them), but a **syntax** error is currently not among them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed in some line of code (or you're writing incomplete code).

#### On line 6 and 7

You type:

```
num=int
gennum = int
```

that's pretty strange, you should give them value, similar to their surrounding line.

```
num = int(0)
gennum = int(0)
```

Even with that value, It will generate another error, that is

```
calculated = int (sum1/gennum)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

because the value of `gennum` is zero. You can't do `anynumber/0`. So, you should properly initialize the variable. Something like,

```
num = int(0)
gennum = int(1)
```

Then, you could continue going on,

```
import random

n= int (0)
sum1=int (0)
temp=int (0)
num=int (0)
gennum = int (1)
count= (0)
outputs= (0)
calculated = int (sum1/gennum)

while count > 3:
    max = int (input("enter a max value:"))
    min = int (input("enter a minimum value:"))
    gennum = int (input("how many numbers do you want to generate?"))
    if min>max:
        temp=min
        min=max
        max=temp
    while n < gennum:
        num=(random.randint(min,max))
        sum1 = sum1 + num
        print (num)
        n=n+1
        count = count + 1
    print("this is the averages",calculated)
print("this is the maximum",max)
```